# React MobX How to display keys of array inside object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm using `react` and `mobx` to create an simple event-app. Now I got an `json`-object which contains a bunch of arrays, each with their own key ( in this case the key is the month). For some reason, I'm unable to display them in my View.

Here is an example of my `json`-data:

```
{
  "events": {
    "November": [{
            "event_name": "some-event",
            "event_date": "2017-11-05"
        },
        {
            "event_name": "some-other-event",
            "event_date": "2017-11-12"
        }
    ],
    "December": [{
            "event_name": "some-event",
            "event_date": "2017-12-05"
        },
        {
            "event_name": "some-other-event",
            "event_date": "2017-12-12"
        }
    ]
   }
}
```

Since I'm using `mobx` I divide the view and the state-files - here is my current state file:

```
import { observable, action, async } from "mobx"

export default class EventState {
   @observable events= [];

   constructor() {
      this.getEvents()
   }

   @action async getEvents() {

    await fetch('/api/events').then(response => {
        if(response.ok){
            response.json().then(data => {

                this.events.slice(0, this.events.length)

                  let actualEvents = {};
                  let months = 'January February March April May June July August September October November December'.split(' ');

                  data.forEach(event => {
                    let date = new Date(event.release_date);
                    let month = date.getMonth();
                    let monthName = months[month]
                    if (!(monthName in actualEvents )) {
                      actualEvents [monthName] = [];
                    }

                    actualEvents [monthName].push(event);
                  });


                  this.events = actualEvents;


               });
            }
            else{
               // error
            }
        });     
     }      

 }

 const eventState = new EventState();
```

Then, in my View fiel I try to display the events, but right now it does show nothing:

```
import React from "react";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import moment from "moment";
import 'moment/locale/de';
import '../../css/main.scss';

import EventState from "./event-state";

@observer
export default class Events extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
       super();

       this.state = new EventState();

   }
   render() {
       return (
        <div>
            <Events state={this.state} events={this.state.events} />
        </div>
      ) 
   }
}

const Events = observer(({ state, event, events }) => (
   <div className="wrapper">
      {state.events.map((event, i) => <Eventdetails state={state} event={event} key={i}/>)}
   </div>
))

const Eventdetails = observer(({ state, event }) => (
  <div>
    // EVENT MONTH HERE?
    <p>{event.name}  {moment(event.event_date).format('LL')}</p>
  </div>
))
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Basically, what I want to achieve is a View like this:

```
November
   - some event 5. November
   - some other event 12. November

December
   - some event 5. December
   - some other event 12. December
```

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To get property names from an object you can use [Object.keys(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
Object.keys(this.events).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key);  // November
  this.events[key].forEach((event) => {
    console.log(event.event_name, event.event_date); // some-event 2017-11-05
  });
})
```

Comment: any idea how to render this in the view?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code here. Please google for async await. You are using it wrong.

```
await fetch('/api/events').then(response => {...});
```

With async await you don't need to add the then callback. You can assign the result to a variable.

```
const response = await fetch('/api/events');
if(response.ok){ ...}
```

Learn about async await and promises first.

Second

```
state.events.map(...);
```

This can't work because map can only be called on an array. But events is an object here. So you must extract all keys as an array and iterate over them with map. (That's what @bennygenel tells you);

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing your observable MobX array with an ordinary array reference in your `getEvents`. Try to use [**replace**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html) instead, so you don't lose the reference:

```
this.events.replace(actualEvents);
```

You also don't need to use `async/await` if you are handling the promise:

```
fetch('/api/events').then(response => { ... });
```